# Difference between 思想，心思 and 思维

Tags: meaning, usage

Is there any difference between the words 思想，心思 and 思维? If possible, pls provide some examples on the usage and situation to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As user6065 mentioned there are many examples can be found.  I'll try to give them a simple explanation:

思维 - The generalization and indirect reaction process of the human brain by various means to objective things, or, your way of 'learning' or 'reacting' to things.
example: Perceptual figurative thinking, logical thinking, Rational thinking

思想 - The action or process of thinking, or, your thoughts / mindset / organization of ideas.
example: open-minded, great thinker

心思 - The 'application' or 'capability' of your thinking.  It could include your thoughts, your emotions / mood etc.
example: attentiveness, being considerate, carelessness

Answer (score 0):

translations with many examples can be found in online dictionaries, note frequency ranks: **思想 269,思维 2330,心思 3682** ,＂汉语同义词词典＂of these 3 only has **心思** which is compared to **心情** (frequency rank 1363) **心情／心思** ［同］名词。指人的内心感情状态。

［异］**［心情]** 着重指处于喜、乐、哀、努、愁等的内心感情状态。常与＂喜悦、欢乐、安逸、平静、舒畅、悲痛、愤怒、惆怅、苦恼、沉重、愁闷、紧张、激动、失望、复杂、崇敬、好、坏＂等词搭配。例（１）胡香仍然坐在自己那个不被人注意的角落里，像坐在针毡上一样，不断地挪动着身体，变换着姿势，心情极为混乱不安。［欧阳山＜圣地＞］（２）一觉过后，疲劳恢复了，心情平静啦。（知侠＜铺草＞）（３）我万分崇敬的心情，瞻仰了这座巍峨、雄伟、庄严的纪念碑。（周定舫＜人民英雄垂不朽＞）（４）我以无限恋念的心情，想起延安的歌声来了。（吴伯箫＜歌声＞）（５）全家人怀着怅惘、抱怨、不安的心情离开了客厅。（小学语文课本＜看球记＞）

**［心思]** 着重指对某事有兴趣，想去做的内心感情状态。常与＂有、没有＂等词语搭配。使用范围比＂心情＂窄。例：（１）他连中学生都不肯当，就是对鸭子有心思。（阵残云＜鸭寮记事＞）（２）我很忙，没有心思管你这些，你认为怎么做好就怎么好啦。（廖清秀，金钱的故事＞）

**［附］**＂心思＂还指念头或脑筋，如＂两边的老人看透了闺女儿子的心思，就愿意把喜事办了＂、＂几个人挖空心思想办法解决这个难题＂。